# At what load is the leakage current quantified for a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, leakage-current

In [this](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/MeanWell_medical_app_note_BF.pdf) document it says "According to IEC 60601-1, the leakage current limits are provided in Table 1."

If the leakage current is due to Y capacitor, the load R and the the parasitic capacitance of the PSU transformer will form an RC divider.

But then the leakage current depends on the load. If the load is big the stray voltage will be big and the leakage current will be small. If the load is small(low impedance setting), then the voltage will  be small but the current will be higher comparing to high load impedance.

For which load the leakage current is measured and presented in datasheets?

Comment: The 'load' in this case is the patient, with said equipment being connected to patient. To avoid this issue many hospitals now use battery powered equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leakage currents referred to are those that flow from either of the DC output terminals to earth. The load between the two DC output wires is irrelevant.

See [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359811/smps-transformer-capacitance-effects/359818#359818) for details about an SMPS's transformer's inter-winding leakage capacitance and how this manifests itself in unwanted output noise **AND** how the output noise is removed by a Y capacitor **BUT** this then produces a common-mode AC power voltage (of low energy) on both output terminals.

Comment: Lets say we want to measure the leakage current ourselves. If the power supply is powered by AC plug; and lets say it is not loaded. And imagine now I short one of the DC power terminal of this power supply to earth by a wire. Now can we say this current is around the leakage current in the data sheet? When you say "DC output terminals to earth. ", do you mean when DC output is shorted to earth?

Comment: Yes you can - this is the leakage (AC) current and won't change with a DC load on the output unless that DC load is complex and has impedances to earth that might shunt away current from your measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Leakage is specified with Line/Neutral short and measure current between that and ground.  Factory tests set for 200uA limit for consumer products, less for medical.  Some standards accept 250uA per unit and 500uA per system.  They also allow 1.4*V for DC tests and additional 10% for reducing test time from 60 s to hold for 1 s with slow DC ramp.

It does not get affected by load Z but E field stress on primary is affected by secondary floating connected to earth ground.  If there is breakdown, it will leak in Hipot with catastrophic failure unless current limited in tester.  ( my fix)

Comment: If I short line and neutral I will trip the fuse what do you mean?

Comment: No it is a common mode HIPOT leakage test, no power.

Comment: If the power supply is powered by AC plug. And lets say it is not loaded. And imagine now I short one of the DC power terminal to earth by a wire. Now can we say this current is around the leakage current in the data sheet?

Comment: The isolation transformer has a capacitance. When the HIPOT charges up line and neutral the voltage drop is across the smallest capacitance or biggest gap.  Grounding secondary bypasses the isolation transformer but probably will never happen for medical apps, but I discovered some suppliers fail Hipot when this setup is used.  ( process failure)  So earth gnd on secondary is not specified. ( user option)

Comment: I tried many powers supplies to get rid of the stray voltages even medical approved ones no luck. Is there in the market a power supply which doesn't cause stray leakage just behave almost like a battery. please see my prev question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360066/noise-due-to-stray-voltages-in-a-data-acquisition-system i have random common mode due to such leakage; and people also want  me to solve this electrick shock issue due to stray. I tell them harmless but they don't want to experience this

Comment: If a SMPS uses improved noise current filtering at higher f with active PFC it may be possible to replace large Y caps with smaller ones thus lower line f leakage almost like WPT chargers

Comment: Others like Brown in Toronto designed 2 stage CM choke with smaller caps to cover a wider freq range and lower leakage.

Comment: Even 200uA is as nuisance when transferred via a pin causing high current density and greater surface skin sensation. or in my case tested by charger to laptop with case corner  to exposed kneecap and feet on grass.

Comment: Maybe I should switch do diff ended inputs and apply such filter after the source before the user  https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/basic/chapter05-p1/chapter05-p1_img0012.ashx?la=en&h=238&w=640

Comment: this I meant: https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/basic/chapter05-p1/chapter05-p1_img0010.ashx?la=en&h=293&w=640

Comment: CM chokes may be bidirectional to reduce ingress and egress and not supposed to cause secondary leakage unless there is a ground fault. Where the caps are placed for 1 stage and/or 2 stage affects attenuation of CM noise in either direction.  If on source , then better for egress, if on CM output, better for ingress. If both then more attenuation in both directions. Groundless cap noise cancellation depends on circuit load impedance and not always balanced.

Comment: depending on the spectrum of your leakage. {line, switcher rate or other} there may be other means to suppress stray effects.

Comment: every ee topic is an ocean itself i get drown when i try to dig any.

Comment: trick is to clarify the problem with specs, and suitable measurements